# find F'(x) for the given F(x)

Tags: calculus

I tried to evaluate $F'(x)$ for the following using the second fundamental theorem of calculus. I was able to find the answers to the first two but not sure how did they get there ?  please show me how. Thanks

$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}F(x) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\int_{-x}^{1}\sqrt{t^2+1}$  the answer to this is  $\sqrt{x^2+1}$

$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}F(x) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \int_{2x}^{x^2}tan^{-1}{t^2} \ dt $ the answer to this is  $2x\ tan^{-1}{x^4} - 2 \ tan^{-1}{4x^2} $

$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}F(x) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x^3}\sqrt{t}\ sin t \ dt$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: For the first problem, note that $\displaystyle\int_{-x}^1\sqrt{t^2+1}\,dt = -\int_1^{-x}\sqrt{t^2+1}\,dt$ and then recall that $$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{g(x)}f(t)\,dt = f(g(x))\cdot g^{\prime}(x)$$

For the second and third problem, recall that $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(t)\,dt = f(h(x))\cdot h^{\prime}(x)-f(g(x))\cdot g^{\prime}(x)$$